# If $a>0$, then $\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1} < \sum_{1}^{n} k^a < \frac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{a+1}$?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading Kazarinoff's "Analytic Inequalities". Here:

> [image]

I don't know how to solve this problem. I have tried induction and some combinations of previously given Inequalities in the book. Until now, I've seen:

- The AMGM inequality;

---

- [image]

---

- [image]

I am aware that there may be an immediate solution with calculus but no calculus was mentioned until the present moment in the book. Is there a non-calculus way to prove that? Could you give me a hint? I prefer a hint and not a full solution.

Comment: Is there a "non-calculus" way to define $k^\alpha$ for irrational $\alpha$?

Comment: Hint: Prove (then use) the fact that, for every positive integer $k$, $$\int_{k-1}^kt^a\,dt\leqslant k^a\leqslant\int_k^{k+1}t^a\,dt$$